# App Limits for Executables in MacOS Screen Time

Tags: macos, catalina, system-settings, screen-time

I would like to play less Minecraft, and MacOS Screen Time seems well-equipped to keep me from using certain applications for more than a specified amount of time using the "App Limits" function. However, the Minecraft game isn't an Application (.app); it actually runs as a Java application through a standalone `java` executable. Thus, MacOS doesn't recognize the game as an application, although it essentially runs as one.

Various other System Preferences panes (i.e. Login Items, Privacy disk access) allow you to directly add executables, but not Screen Time. Is there a way for me to limit their usage?